# Stop IntelliJ from opening same file twice in horizontal split view

Tags: intellij-idea, view

googled this but didn't have success. 
I'm using the horizontal split view of IntelliJ (the view that allow us to have files on the upper and bottom part of the screen). 
The problem is that whenever I search for a file using the search for a target feature, instead of opening the already opened file which is located on the upper files' list, it opens again on the bottom list but I'd like it to open the one that's already open on the upper list.

Do you know how to change this behavior?

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Oh, ok then. I'll do it, thanks!

Comment: @VandersonAssis Can you link to the issue you created?